# How to enable systemd instantiated service with puppet?

Tags: puppet

I've got the following puppet service:

```
service { "getty@ttyUSB0.service": 
    provider => systemd,
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
}
```

When I try to apply this configuration on my client, it throws the following error:

> err: /Stage[main]//Node[puppetclient]/Service[getty@ttyUSB0.service]/enable: change from false to true failed: Could not enable getty@ttyUSB0.service:

The service is running fine and I can make sure it's started on system boot by adding a symlink to getty.target.wants:

> ln -s /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@ttyUSB0.service

Of source, I could go ahead and remove "enable => true" from the service definition and include a the symlink manually in the puppet configuration, but shouldn't puppet take care of this? Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The systemd provider in Puppet today only uses two commands for the service `enable` state:

- `systemctl is-enabled <unit>`, checking return code for the current enable state
- `systemctl enable/disable <unit>` to change it

The enable command throws an error when you enable an instance of the getty@ service that doesn't already exist:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable getty@ttyUSB0.service
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
```

This is then causing the error shown in Puppet (though stderr doesn't seem to be displayed).

It looks to me like a gap in systemd that you aren't able to enable new instances of a template.  There's already [BZ#752774 in Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=752774), but the comments suggest it might not be added any time soon.

You might be better off filing a [feature request](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/issues/new) against Puppet to add support specifically for enabling new instances.  In your feature request I'd suggest linking to [Lennart's explanation of unit instances](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html) for background.