# Puppet generated systemd unit files?

Tags: puppet

I expected the following to actually start my service:

```
service{'legacy':
  ensure   => running,
  start    => "cd /vagrant/nginx-reverse-proxy/legacy && /usr/bin/bundle exec ruby app.rb -o 127.0.0.1 -e production -p ${port}",
  provider => 'systemd',
}
```

I know and undertand that the start command isn't correct, but I don't know how to start the actual Ruby Sinatra app. I actually expected something like this to work:

```
service{'legacy':
  ensure   => running,
  command  => "cd /vagrant/nginx-reverse-proxy/legacy && /usr/bin/bundle exec ruby app.rb -o 127.0.0.1 -e production -p ${port}",
  provider => 'systemd',
}
```

Somewhat like cron. I'm used to daemontools, and systemd's model is completely different. Do I have to create the unit file myself? And link the unit file?

I've found [How to enable systemd instantiated service with puppet?](https://serverfault.com/q/395434/155993) which starts some kind of USB device. I also found [camptocamp/puppet-systemd](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-systemd) which seems to manage systemd itself. Puppet's docs on [systemd service provider](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#service-provider-systemd) are rather sparse in details.

How does one create a systemd service using Puppet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a unit file. The command attribute you've specified there isn't actually a [valid attribute](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/type.html#service) for the service resource

You're best off adding an [ERB template](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_template_erb.html) with your unit file, here's an example:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Ruby Service
Wants=basic.target
After=basic.target network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/vagrant/nginx-reverse-proxy/legacy
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bundle exec ruby app.rb -o 127.0.0.1 -e production -p 4567"
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, set up the template in Puppet and make sure you refresh systemd. Some example code:

```
file { '/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service':
  mode    => '0644',
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
  content => template('modulename/myservice.systemd.erb'),
}~>
exec { 'myservice-systemd-reload':
  command     => 'systemctl daemon-reload',
  path        => [ '/usr/bin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin' ],
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

Now that's done, you can start the service as normal:

```
service { 'myservice':
  ensure   => running,
  enable   => true,
  provider => provider,
}
```